# Accessing different flextable in each tabpanel separately on button click event

Tags: gwt, flextable

I have a TabContainer in GWt with 4 TabPanels. In 1st tab panel I have 7 radio buttons listed down and on selection on a radio button a set of image and a table is to be loaded.

Now If I click on submit button I want to access each flex table differently which I am not getting rite now. Structure of the table is shown below

[image]
<sub>(source: [expertsmind.com](http://www.expertsmind.com/CMSImages/1323_html%20control.png))</sub>

This is just a demo of how my GUI looks. Also when I retrieve data column wise then for the text box I am getting only its HTML code not its value. So pls tell me how could I use table id to retrieve data from text boxes from flextable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your TabPanel has an activity above it, the easiest solution would be to give the activity access to each FlexTable you have, or the relevant data you want. If each tab is a separate class, simply put a getData() function or something similar, and then query each tab from the overlying activity that is handling your logic.